# Request for the proof of a theorem

Tags: group-theory

I am sincerely requesting a proof of the following theorem from anyone willing to do so. We are about to learn about Sylow groups and simple groups next, and I want to get further ahead of the game by understanding this theorem because I have read ahead a little bit.

FYI, we are using Algebra by Artin.

**Theorem:** If G is a finite group with a subgroup H such that $|G|∤([G:H])!$ then G contains a non-trivial proper normal subgroup containing H.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried proving it?

Comment: Yes I have, but it seems out of my reach right now because I don't know what 'simple' means and haven't learned about permutation representations yet.

Comment: A Simple group is a group with no nontrivial normal subgroups, but I suspect you'll need the Sylow theorems for this one.

Comment: Could anyone guide me along? I just want to study with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the guides:

Define an action of $\;G\;$ on the set $\;X\;$ of left cosets of $\;H\;$ by

$$g\cdot(xH)\mapsto(gx)H$$

Prove the above indeed is an action (almost trivial).

Now, look at the induced homomorphism $\;\phi:G\to\text{ Sym}_X\cong S_n\;,\;\;n:=[G:H]\;$ ,  from the above action. Prove that $\;\ker\phi\;$ is the maximal normal subgroup of $\;G\;$ *contained in* $\;H\;$  . If you want, you can try to prove that in fact

$$\ker\phi=\bigcap_{g\in G}g^{-1}Hg=:\text{ the socle of}\;H$$

Apply now the first isomorphism theorem to $\;\phi\;$ and use the given info to reach the desired result.